# Creating tables in BigQuery from Dataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt, dataform

I am not able to create tables in BigQuery using GCP Dataform. All the tables that I am creating are showing as temporary tables and hence not visible in BigQuery. Below is my source to fetch data from a table of BigQuery.

```
config {
 type: "declaration",
 database: "xx-prd",
 schema: "mixpanel",
 name: "table1",
 description: "Source test."
}
```

And this is how I am creating a table

```
config {
    type: "table"
}

select * 
FROM ${ref('table1')}
where DATE(created_at) = "2023-05-10"
limit 10
```

When I compile the above code, I can see in the job output in both Dataform and BigQuery UI that a temporary table is created. I tried including `schema`, `bigquery` and `database` in config of above definition with table, hoping that it will change something however nothing changed. I have used type as table, view and incremental, every-time, a temporary table is created.

So I wanted to know how to use an existing BigQuery table as source and create a table in any particular schema of BigQuery from it.